# PlainSocketImpl.write hangs on writing to many sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, concurrency

I have a thread writing the same 40K byte array to 16 sockets  (iterates on the sockets array and every sockets is sent the entire byte array).
This repeats in a loop every 100 ms.
the sender is an android nexus 7 device and the receiver is windows 7.

after about 30 seconds one of the writers hang on:

```
Posix.sendtoBytes(FileDescriptor, Object, int, int, int, InetAddress, int) line: not available [native method]  
Posix.sendto(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int, InetAddress, int) line: 146 
BlockGuardOs.sendto(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int, InetAddress, int) line: 177  
IoBridge.sendto(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int, InetAddress, int) line: 473  
PlainSocketImpl.write(byte[], int, int) line: 507   
PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl, byte[], int, int) line: 46  
PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(byte[], int, int) line: 269
```

Could this be a bug in android ? is it a concurrency problem or network problem ?
Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reader is slow reading, so its receive buffer fills up, so your send buffer fills up, so you block.